# How can I get unswitched power froma switched circuit without running new cable?

Tags: electrical

I want to get unswitched power into my carport attic to install unswitched electrical outlets.  Right now, power into the carport is switched, controlled by two switches, one for carport can lights and one for driveway flood lights.  There are a couple of outside junction boxes (outside wall and outside breezeway ceiling) as the carport replaced an existing screened porch.  I CANNOT run new wire from the light switch box to any of the junction boxes or from one junction box to another (it can be done if I opted to tear up wall and ceiling, which I don't want to do).  From the attached diagram, is there a way to use existing wires to make a hot wire in the attic junction box?  Maybe a pigtail, or moving the existing power into the switch to power into the can lights or flood lights?  The diagram does not show ground wires, and light gray wires represent white wires.  Yellow cable was installed by electrician during the carport construction in 2015 (I assume the white and black cables are from the original build in 1989) [image: Carport wiring diagram]

Comment: In the box on the outside of the laundry, is the unswitched hot on the same circuit as the hot coming into the 3-gang in the laundry room?

Comment: Also, are the carport attic lights controlled by the attic switch already?

Comment: I too am bugged the way the neutrals are tied together in the "outside facing; wall of laundry" junction box.  Neutrals are not promiscuous like grounds; they must stay with their hots only.

Answer (score 1):

1. Decommission the switches.  You can leave them in place, just adjust the wiring behind them to always be "on" by pulling the wires from the switch and wire nut them together, two wires per switch.
2. Add switches in the garage near their load after the loads are branched off the feed.
3. Outlets in attic now always have power.